# selenium webdriver on virtual machine

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, virtual-machine, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm working on a virtual machine using Selenium WebDriver.  I'm trying to run tests on the machine I work on (again, virtual) and I'm getting a NoClassDefFoundError on the line where I instantiate my driver:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary,ffProfile);
```

So, being on the virtual machine, I did some research and found I could use RemoteWebDriver. After trying this, I still get the same error.  Any suggestions?  I feel like this should run the same as being on a physical box, but it doesn't.  It works perfectly on a physical machine.

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/io/Resources at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.onlyOverrideThisIfYouKnowWhatYouAreDo‌​ing(FirefoxProfile.java:123)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.<init>(FirefoxProfile.java:86)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.<init>(FirefoxProfile.java:79)
at line 63 in my class is where it breaks: File profile = new File(PROFILE); //PROFILE = where FF profile is (63) FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile(profile)
```

Comment: What's the full error & stack trace?

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/io/Resources
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.onlyOverrideThisIfYouKnowWhatYouAreDoing(FirefoxProfile.java:123)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.<init>(FirefoxProfile.java:86)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.<init>(FirefoxProfile.java:79)`

at line 63 in my class is where it breaks:
`File profile = new File(PROFILE); //PROFILE = where FF profile is
(63) FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile(profile)`

Comment: Check your classpath to see whether that guvava libraries are corrctly defined. Print your classpath in command line or sysout System.getproperty("java.classpath") in the code. If you are using maven check runtime dependencies.

Comment: ok - found that there WAS a library missing that I needed.  However, now I'm getting another error:    

`org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new sesion. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the profile at the remoth machin

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles